# Python Save Image from URL to ZipFile

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I save an image from a URL to a zipfile? For example I am trying to save [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Wurmseegurke.jpg) to a zipfile but it keeps throwing the error "File not found".

What am I doing wrong?

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from tempfile import TempFile
import urllib.request

with TemporaryFile() as tf:
    with ZipFile(tf, mode='w') as zf:
        image_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Wurmseegurke.jpg'
        url = urllib.request.open(image_url)
        filename = image_url.split('/')[-1]
        zf.write(filename, url.read())
```

Here is the full error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Wurmseegurke.jpg'

Comment: Have you looked at writestr()?

Comment: @JakobF That did the trick...

Comment: I thought that writestr wrote strings only, so I didn't even consider it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TemporaryFile` get deleted after it is closed, so your image wont be available after it was written into it.
You need to use writestr() to create a 'file object' in the zip:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib.request
import os


image_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Wurmseegurke.jpg'
url = urllib.request.urlopen(image_url)
filename = image_url.split('/')[-1]

zipPath = '/tmp/%s.zip' % filename
with ZipFile(zipPath, mode='w') as zf:
    zf.writestr(filename, url.read())
print(os.path.exists(zipPath))  # probing a zip file was written!
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Changing it from write() to writestr() is what fixed it, thanks! I had to use TemporaryFile for an existing process so that has to be left unchanged.